# Dataset of Facebook Users Connectivity

Tags: data-request, social-media

Is there any dataset available of Facebook users which shows how people are connected with each other? So that I can use that dataset to do some research on access control in social networks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Facebook has the [Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api) so you can construct your own queries and collect as much data as you want.

Otherwise, there are some collected resources described in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3340810/2327328) (warning: from 2010 and maybe involving hacked data).

- [Online Social Neworks](http://odysseas.calit2.uci.edu/doku.php/public:online_social_networks) from UC Irvine
- [100 million Facebook pages leaked as torrent](http://www.itproportal.com/2010/7/28/100-million-facebook-pages-leaked-torrent-site/)

---

If you don't require Facebook, there are much better resources for Twitter ([datasets](http://www.kdnuggets.com/2014/08/interesting-social-media-datasets.html+) and [public search/stream API](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public) access)